# How to set up hibernate to use Glassfish connection pool?

Tags: java, hibernate, glassfish

I have set up a connection pool in Glassfish with a jndi resource for it also setup. I am stumped on how to configure hibernate to go get it.

I have come across alot of write ups to configure it to use C3P0 connection pool. Well I am lost. I found that I need to set:

```
hibernate.connection.datasource
hibernate.jndi.url 
hibernate.jndi.class 
hibernate.connection.username
hibernate.connection.password
```

- Would datasource be the same as the `hibernate.connection.datasource` set in the connection pool?
- What would hibernate.jndi.class be?
- Are hibernate.connection.username and hibernate.connection.password for the connection to the database or to the appserver? I assume this is to the database, but why do I need them since that is all set in the appserver?

Comment: Have you seen this? http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-optional-jndi

Comment: I actually had been to that page, but not that section. Maybe it is just still to early in the morning, but it still kinda cryptic to me. Thanks for the link though.

Comment: @Jer That seems to be to place the make the SessionFactory available as a JNDI resource. Is that the same thing? Basically I am just concerned about getting hibernate to use the Glassfish connection pool.

Comment: This seems like it will help:
http://www.hildeberto.com/2008/11/configuring-glassfish-to-support.html

Comment: @Jer That's not what the @jschoen is looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [article about hibernate basics](http://www.developer.com/open/article.php/3559931/Hibernate-Basics.htm) seems to have the info you will want.  Search for the string 'Using a JNDI DataSource'.  Listing 2 is important.  You may want to compare it against listing 1...

It looks like you can skip c3po, so many of your subquestions do not apply.